# jQuery ajax remains pending / stalled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I've read a bunch of other SO threads but none of them had an answer that worked for me.

I have a simple jQuery script that sends some data over ajax to a Node.js server. Basically this:

```
$.ajax
  url: '/v2/send/[id]'
  method: 'POST'
  data: 'test'
  success: ->
    console.log 'Complete', arguments
```

When I run this code, in the network tab in Chrome the request appears but it's ["stalled"](https://gyazo.com/439b11dc9968c157a8dbf2ada5f1e394). It stays that way for minutes, I have read posts from other people where it eventually did send but so far I haven't noticed that happening.

I'm developing the server as well, and I'm logging every request to the application, so I can see that in fact nothing comes in.

I currently have nothing else in my script ([this is the whole thing](http://pastebin.com/NRBVsCrs)).

So far I've checked and verified:

- That jQuery is loaded (`$` is set)
- That the 'submit' event is in fact triggered (by adding an `alert` which popped up)
- That the request is being created (AjaxStart and AjaxSend happen)
- That the URL is correct (right-clicking the request in the network tab -> 'open in new tab' shows me the data I wanted)
- That there are no other requests / connections getting in the way (I only have [5 other items](https://gyazo.com/ed989898def5f9ec9bcb05fdcb5eb251) in the network tab)
- That my server actually logs all requests (I hit it with a bunch of random requests using Postman and they all showed)

Am I missing something obvious here, or is jQuery or Chrome at fault? How can I fix this to actually send the request?

Comment: Have you tried it in another browser?

Comment: seems to be the node.js ajaxed page

Comment: an you acces the ajaxed page directly,do you have a infinite loop in that page?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist it works in Firefox, this is specifically a Chrome issue.

Comment: your ajax is calling a different url

Comment: @madalinivascu can you explain what you mean by "seems to be the node.js ajaxed page"? The URL I'm calling with ajax is different from the page I am on. The page name is the same, but the path is different.

Comment: you are calling `/v2/send/[id]` in the ajax call but in the screen i only see `/v2/send` this may cause a infinite loop or something similar

Comment: When you right-click to open in new tab, is that also sending a POST as you are doing in ajax? Or is it sending as a GET?

Comment: @madalinivascu I am definitely calling `/v2/send/[id]` https://gyazo.com/e87457fd5ec6c246da4cd74887d083af

Comment: @csum When I open the url in my browser it is GET of course, but I used Express's `route.all()` in my application for testing so that doesn't matter. Also additionally all requests get logged before any routing happens, and the ajax request doesn't even get to that point.

Comment: try `data: {test:'test'} ` and `method: 'GET'`

Comment: @madalinivascu I gave that a try, unfortunately it does not make a difference. The request is still "pending".

Comment: The network tab shows only 1 other request to your domain: `/v2/widget/[id]`. Have you tested that url via ajax to see if it succeeds? `$.get(widgetUrl, function () { ... })`

Comment: I can open the url in my browser, and request it through Postman, and in both cases I get the expected response. Using `$.get` or any other jQuery AJAX function results in requests that remain pending / stalled, and never even hit the server.

Comment: I left this code last night without any changes, not working. When I got back this morning and tried it again - it worked. Can anyone reproduce the issue or advise me as to what could have caused it? It's a rather critical element in our application so I want to make sure this doesn't happen to end users when we roll out the application.